# How to check a radio button in cucumber?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I'm using cucumber with RoR (with either webrat or capybara)

How can I write a step to check a radio button? I've tried "choose" or "select" but it can't find my radio button. 
I'm not sure what to do, as I have in fact 2 inputs with the same name (the 2 radio buttons belonging to the same "group")

Thanks

Example of html

```
<form name="myform" action="http://www.mydomain.com/myformhandler.cgi" method="POST">

<input type="radio" name="group1" value="Milk"> Milk<br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="Butter" checked> Butter<br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="Cheese"> Cheese

</form>
```

Comment: I mean selected one of the option of the radion buttons (pressing a button)

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is to `choose` the id (generated by Rails) of the radio button.

```
 <form name="myform" action="http://www.mydomain.com/myformhandler.cgi" method="POST">

    <input type="radio" name="group1" value="Milk" id="group1_milk"> Milk<br>
    <input type="radio" name="group1" value="Butter" checked id="group1_butter"> Butter<br>
    <input type="radio" name="group1" value="Cheese" id="group1_cheese"> Cheese

  </form>
```

and do

```
choose("group1_milk").
```

That will work even if more radio buttons have the same options.

Answer (score 3):

In your step definition add line:

```
choose('A Radio Button')
```

Cucumber uses Capybara, you can read more about it here: https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara

Comment: Yes but I want to choose "Milk". Can I do choose("Milk") ?

Comment: Yes, it should be possible this way.

Comment: So I have two groups of radio button with Milk. How can I specify with 'Milk' to choose ?

Comment: @mb14 within 'scope' do
choose('milk')
end